# How to transfer the data from my current sd-card to my new sd-card?

Tags: sd-card, data-transfer

I got my Samsung Galaxy J3 crown in December and put my previous 64 GB card in it and used it for about 4 months. Then I got a 128 GB card and put it in my phone.

I am unsure how to transfer everything from the old to the new card especially because the default download location is there. I cant find it in the settings and really need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PC and an USB SD-card reader I would do the following:

1. Unmount/eject the old SD-card (or simply power down the Android phone)
2. Place it into the USB SD-card reader and connect it to your PC
3. Copy all the files using the Explorer or a similar file manager to a folder on your hard disk
4. Eject/unmount the USB SD-card reader
5. Replace the old SD-card with the new SD-card
6. Connect the USB SD-card reader with the new SD-card inserted to your PC
7. Copy all the files from the folder on your hard disk to the new SD-card
8. Eject/unmount the USB SD-card reader
9. Place the new SD-card in your Android phone

If something goes wrong you can still switch back to your old SD-card and you can start another try.